# Como preencher um EditorFor como o nome do usuário logado

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, razor, asp.net-identity

Tenho uma `View`, onde o usuário deve preencher alguns campos, e tem um ultimo campo que eu deixei ele `disable`, e gostaria que neste campo aparece-se o nome do usuário, porém como faço para preencher?

`Model`:

```
public class CombustivelModels
{
    [Key]
    public int CombustivelId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal km_inicial { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal km_final { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal litros { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal valor { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

`View`:

```
        <div class="form-group">
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
             <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => User.Identity.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled=""} })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
             </div>
        </div>
```

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém ao tentar salvar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você coloca uma anotação de `[Required]` e usa o `EditFor` ele vai criar o imput com `data-val="true"` que já vai fazer essa validação para vc.

Quando você fez o `@Html.EditorFor(model => User.Identity.Name,` ele gerou um Imput com no name diferente de `UserId`...

Como não existe nenhum imput no form com o name de `UserId` ele vai tentar validar e não vai conseguir fazer o bind dessa propriedade do seu objeto VM e vai colocar a mensagem na tela...

Essa mensagem aparece onde você fez `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId,`

O que eu faria nesse caso seria apenas exibir o nome dele em um imput pegando com `User.Identity.Name` e não ter essa propriedade no VM de cadastro.

No lado do servidor você pega o usuário logado e joga no banco de dados (acredito que seja um CRUD que você está fazendo).

Se não consegui sanar a dúvida me fala que melhoro.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

No seu Model você tira a anotação como abaixo:

**De:**

```
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
```

**Para:**

```
    public string UserId { get; set; }
```

**Na view você remove:**

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

No controller eu acredito que você está recebendo um `CombustivelModels` e com as mudanças que eu sugeri ele vai estar preenchido, mas com a propriedade `UserId`  `null`

No código do controller você pega o nome do usuário e joga na propriedade.

```
meuObjQueVeioDaView.UserId = User.Identity.Name
//....
//resto do código
```

Só confirma se o `User.Identity.Name` vai funcionar no controller, acho que vai, se não conseguir me fala.

Comment: Cara, eu entendi, mas nao sei como solucionar, poderia me indicar, ou melhorar sua resposta?

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel da uma olhada e vê se ficou melhor.

Comment: Perfeito. certinho obrigado.